# WCF not returning any error when downloading via Stream and error occurs in the middle

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

i wonder if anyone encountered this:

i have a WCF service that returns a Stream (custom i've created).

during the download, it may be that an error occurs, and i want the client to know it.

the problem is, that when error occurs during download, the client stream receives "0 bytes" from the Stream.Read, and finishes (successfully) instead of exception / any other error.

is there any solution for this? it seems that WCF ignores any read errors and just closes the stream afterward.

code:

server:

```
public interface IService1
   {

      [OperationContract]
      [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         UriTemplate = "Data")]
         Stream GetFileStream();
}


public class Service1 : IService1
   {

      public System.IO.Stream GetFileStream()
      {
         return new MyCustomStream();         
      }
}
```

implementation:

```
 public class MyCustomStream : Stream
   {
      FileStream _Stream;

      private bool wasRead = false;
      public MyCustomStream()
      {
         _Stream = new FileStream(@"someFileOnDisk", FileMode.Open,
                              FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

      }

~MyCustomStream()
      {
         if (_Stream != null)
         {
            _Stream.Dispose();
         }

      }

public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
      {
         if (!wasRead)
         {
            wasRead = true;
            return _Stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
         }
         else
         {
            throw new Exception("ERROR!!!!");
         }         
      }

public override void Close()
      {
         _Stream.Close();
      }
```

client:

```
internal static HttpWebRequest InitializeRequest(Uri url, string i_RelativeURL, int i_Timeout, string i_MethodType, string i_ContentType)
      {

         System.Net.HttpWebRequest newRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(CombineURI(url.AbsoluteUri, i_RelativeURL));
         newRequest.Proxy = null; // We are not using proxy
         newRequest.Timeout = i_Timeout;
         newRequest.Method = i_MethodType;
         newRequest.ContentType = i_ContentType;

         return newRequest;
      }

static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         HttpWebRequest request = InitializeRequest(new Uri(@"http://localhost/WCFTest/Service1.svc"), "data", 999999, "GET", "application/json");

         using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
         {
            using (Stream curStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
               byte[] buffer = new byte[2000000]; // ~2MB
               int read = curStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
               int blockToWrite = read;
               while (read > 0)
               {
                  // If we reach to ~1MB of data - write it to the disk
                  if (blockToWrite >= 1000000)
                  {
                     blockToWrite = 0;
                  }

                  read = curStream.Read(buffer, blockToWrite, buffer.Length - blockToWrite); // Returns 0 if exception occurs on server side.
                  blockToWrite += read;
               }
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: How dows your implementation of `IService1` look like?

Comment: @khlr - sorry, added to the post the implementation - very simple - just return the stream.

Comment: Throw WebFaultException from your service and catch it in your client.

Comment: hi @Hakunamatata, i'm using .net 3.5, and WebFaultException doesn't exist there. 
nevertheless, i've converted the projects to .net 4.5 - and now i get an exception in the client side, but it's "IOException" because the server closes the stream.

i've thrown: 
throw new WebFaultException<string>("error", HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

is there a way to receive that error? because the client as i said throws IOException

Comment: Create a new data contract on your service side say ErrorData with whatever details you want to send back like Message,Full Stack Trace, Error Line etc as Data Members and then when you throw an Exception form service throw it as WebFaultException<ErrorData> by that way you have required details at your client end.

Comment: @Hakunamatata i understand, but the client receives IOException because the stream is closed, it doesn't get WebFaultException